# Alpine.JS slideshow not sliding

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, alpine.js

I've got a slideshow for displaying customer feedback, created in alpine.js and laravel. It's drawing comments from the database as it's supposed to, but the actual sliding functionality is not working.

Could anyone explain what I've done wrong? It's based loosely from this article: https://codebase-frontend-library.github.io/codebase-4/docs/8-alpinejs-components/alpinejs-slideshows/

Here is the code:

```
    @php
    $commentIds = $comments->pluck('id')->toArray();
@endphp

@foreach ($comments as $comment)
    <div class="is-centered" x-data="{ activeSlide: 1, slides: {{ json_encode($commentIds) }} }">
        <div x-show="activeSlide === {{ $comment->id }}">
            <h1 class="title is-2">{{ $comment->feed }}</h1>
            <span class="font-semibold is-italic has-text-weight-bold">
                <p>{{ $comment->customer }}</p>
            </span>
            <span class="is-size-7">{{ $comment->date }}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach

<div class="slider_buttons">
    <button class="button" x-on:click="activeSlide = activeSlide === 1 ? slides.length : activeSlide - 1">←</button>
    <button class="button" x-on:click="activeSlide = activeSlide === slides.length ? 1 : activeSlide + 1">→</button>
</div>
```

Comment: How/where do you load alpine.js? Any errors in your browser's DevConsole?

Comment: Can't find any errors in the DevConsole. For testing, my project is receiving alpine from a CDN: <script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>

Comment: Update: For comparison, I included the hard code version on the same file <div class="my-3" x-data="{ activeSlide: 1, slides: [1, 2, 3] }">
  <div class="relative">
    <!-- Slides -->
    <div x-show="activeSlide === 1">
      <!-- Slide -->
    </div>
    <div x-show="activeSlide === 2">
      <!-- Slide -->
    </div>
    <div x-show="activeSlide === 3">
      <!-- Slide -->
    </div> And it works. I think the problem is at x-data="{ activeSlide: 1, slides: [1, 2, 3] }", the mysql version seems to be stuck on slide one

Comment: Right. Looks like the problem is you have everything inside the loop. Try placing `<div class="is-centered" x-data="{ activeSlide: 1, slides: {{ json_encode($commentIds) }} }">` and its closing `</div>` _outside_ of your `@foreach`. Only place your "slides" inside the loop

Comment: Hm, your "hardcoded" example (and the example from the link you posted) has `<div class="relative">` which is missing from your original code.

Comment: Please share more details about the problem. Are you sure that MySQL and Laravel are involved? Is the markup generated properly? If yes, share the **generated** markup. If not, share what you've tried to generate the markup properly. It could be a good idea to start with **static** markup first, and then generate it through Blade

Answer (score -1):

Three things look off here:

- You're looping the whole slider
- You're missing the `<div class="relative">...</div>`
- Your `<button>`s are outside of that missing `<div class="relative">...</div>`

Try changing your code to this:

```
@php
    $commentIds = $comments->pluck('id')->toArray();
@endphp
<div class="is-centered" x-data="{ activeSlide: 1, slides: {{ json_encode($commentIds) }} }">
    <div class="relative">
        @foreach ($comments as $comment)
        <div x-show="activeSlide === {{ $comment->id }}">
            <h1 class="title is-2">{{ $comment->feed }}</h1>
            <span class="font-semibold is-italic has-text-weight-bold">
                <p>{{ $comment->customer }}</p>
            </span>
            <span class="is-size-7">{{ $comment->date }}</span>
        </div>
        @endforeach
        <div class="slider_buttons">
            <button class="button" x-on:click="activeSlide = activeSlide === 1 ? slides.length : activeSlide - 1">←</button>
            <button class="button" x-on:click="activeSlide = activeSlide === slides.length ? 1 : activeSlide + 1">→</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```